# Duda sobre comportamiento de una variable de tipo entero

Tags: c++

He hecho el siguiente programa que calcula la herencia en función del número de hijos:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int leer_datoi()
{
    int dato;

    cin >> dato;

    return dato;    
}

double leer_datod()
{
    double dato;

    cin >> dato;

    return dato;
}

void calcular_herencia()
{
    double herencia, mayor;
    int num_hijos;

    do{
    cout << "Ingrese el importe de la herencia:\t";
    herencia=leer_dato_d();
    cout << "\n";

    if(herencia<=0)
        cout << "ERROR. Ingrese una cantidad positiva\n" << endl;
   } while(herencia<=0);

   do{
      cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de hijos:\t\t";
      num_hijos=leer_dato_i();
      cout << "\n";

      if(num_hijos<=0)
        cout << "ERROR. Ingrese una cantidad positiva\n" << endl;
  } while(num_hijos<=0);

    if(num_hijos<=4)
    {
        herencia=herencia/num_hijos;
        cout << "La herencia para cada hijo es:\t\t" << herencia << "\n" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        mayor=herencia/2;
        herencia=mayor/(num_hijos-1);
        cout << "La herencia para el hijo mayor es:\t" << mayor << "\n" << endl;
        cout << "La herencia para el resto de hijos es:\t" <<  herencia << "\n" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    calcular_herencia();    

    return 0;
}
```

Lo probé y funciona normal. Luego, por curiosidad puse un valor no entero al ingresar la cantidad de hijos (digamos 4.5) e igual el programa funcionó, lo cual me parece algo raro ya que la variable `num_hijos` es de tipo entero.

Mi pregunta es:

¿A qué se debe esto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando el programa se encuentra con esto:

```
int dato;
cin >> dato;
```

Intenta leer un entero de la entrada estándar. Si el primer caracter que se encuentra es un dígito numérico o el signo (`+` o `-`), el `stream` entenderá que puede empezar a extraer un entero. ¿Cuando termina? Como está leyendo un entero terminará cuando ya no pueda extraer más dígitos, cosa que sucede, según tu caso, cuando se encuentra con el punto. En ese momento deja de leer y te devuelve en `dato` el número leído hasta ese momento.

Es decir, ante una entrada `4.5`, en `dato` se almacena un `4` y en el buffer de entrada se queda el residuo `.5`. Puedes comprobar que esto es cierto con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
  std::string cadena;
  int variable;

  std::cin >> variable >> cadena;
  std::cout << variable << '\n' << cadena << '\n';
}
```

Ante una entrada tipo `4.5` el programa imprime lo siguiente:

```
4
.5
```

Así pues, como puedes observar, el programa no hace ninguna magia sino que se limita a darte lo que le pides.

Otra situación diferente la tendríamos si la conversión la hiciésemos una vez se ha leído el dato. Por ejemplo imagínate que en vez de leer un entero se leyese un `double` y después se intentase almacenar ese número en un entero. Algo así:

```
double temporal;

std::cin >> temporal;
int dato = static_cast<int>(temporal);
```

En este caso `cin` leerá el número completo `4.5` y lo almacenará en `temporal`. La conversión a entero provocará un truncado de los decimales, por lo que la parte decimal (`.5`) se perderá y en `dato` se almacenará finalmente la parte entera (`4`).

¿Dónde está la diferencia en ambos casos? El resultado almacenado en `dato` no cambia, es el mismo en ambos casos, sin embargo en que en este segundo ejemplo el buffer de entrada queda limpio, sin residuos.

Si modificamos un poco el ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
  int v1, v2;

  std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
  std::cout << v1 << '\n' << v2 << '\n';
}
```

E introduces, por ejemplo, `4.5 6` el programa imprimirá lo siguiente:

```
4
0
```

¿De dónde viene ese 0? Lo que sucede es que tras leer el primer entero en el buffer de entrada se queda el siguiente residuo: `.5 6`. Ese punto inicial le impide leer correctamente un segundo entero. Al producirse el error en la lectura se activan los flags de error de `cin` y el *stream* se bloquea hasta que dichos flags se reinicien.

Con este ejemplo se ve lo importante que es limpiar el buffer de entrada antes de realizar una lectura:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
  int v1, v2;

  if( !(std::cin >> v1) )
    std::cin.clear();

  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');

  std::cin >> v2;

  std::cout << v1 << '\n' << v2;
}
```

Donde:

- El método `clear` limpia los flags de error del *stream*. Esta acción solo se ejecuta cuando la lectura del primer entero falla (por ejemplo si introduces un caracter).
- El método `ignore` permite descartar caracteres del *stream*. En este caso se descartarán todos los caracteres que se encuentren hasta llegar al primer salto de línea.
- `numeric_limits` es una clase que permite obtener los valores límite para cada tipo de dato (recordemos que los rangos suelen ser dependientes de la máquina). En este caso obtiene el número más alto que puede ser almacenado en un entero con signo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta detallada.

Answer (score 3):

El programa al hacer la captura de datos de entrada a través de `cin` efectivamente procesará el dato como de tipo de doble presición. Al hacerse la asignación a la variable local `dato` en la función `leer_datoi`, la parte fraccional se truncará y se tomará solo la parte entera.

Puedes hacer la siguiente prueba:

```
int leer_datoi() 
{
   int dato;

   cin >> dato;
   cout << dato;

   return dato;    
}
```

Deberás ver aquí un **4** como salida de pantalla

Answer (score 0):

Las variables tipo entero guardan enteros. Si ingresas alguna variable con coma, guarda el entero. Esto sirve en muchos casos para desglosar enteros... Ej: 17022017 es una fecha tipo ddmmaaaa, si queremos guardarnos el dia definimos: 
Int dia = 17022017 / 1000000
Lo que nos da por resultado 17.022017... pero al guardarse solo el entero entonces dia == 17